# Script to perform a local backup of files stored in Google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

I am about to store all my critical files on Google Drive. Before doing this, I'd like to make sure I have a proper backup in case I delete accidentally files.

There are tools to perform backups / restore of Google Drive (e.g. backupify). However, I'd like to keep it simple and have a script running on my PC that let's say once a day takes a backup of files stored in Google Drive.

Does anyone has a script to perform this ? The script can be on PC or Mac.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Hugues

Comment: One thing to be careful of is meta data. Backing up the content of a file is fairly easy,and I'm sure there are many scripts that will help you. But, backing up permissions, properties, comments, etc is a bit trickier since they don't have analogues on most storage systems. So make sure you are clear what you need to back up,and what you are prepared to lose.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to keep a local backup of your files would probably be to install the Google Drive application. There are versions for both PC and Mac:

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2374989

Jay