# How to automatically-selectively backup critical files on edit?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, backup

I have just accidentally deleted one week of coding source files, and even testdisk does not restore them. Even executable jars gone... I use ubuntu. I dont want that happen ever again. How to sufficiently and efficiently make automatic backups (clones) of selected `critical` files to a different location e.g. home?
I use java, and eclipse as IDE, but this could be any file i work with. E.g. i select  certain file, because i can accidentally delete it, so this lightweight backup tool would automatically update it in saved backup location according to saved changes. So if it is lost in working directory, as in my case, i can just take it from backup site on local machine. Pls help. I feel devastated...

[cwatch](https://github.com/kse/cwatch) might be a solution i am looking for, but it is too complicated.

p.s. i am aware of question [Script to perform a local backup of files stored in Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835442/script-to-perform-a-local-backup-of-files-stored-in-google-drive)

google services not ok for me.

Comment: Why dont you use version control? Github?

Comment: i deleted it by trying to configure git, and overplayed with it without having backup copies locally

Comment: That is unfortunate but my honest advice would still be to GitHub or Bitbucket. I also messed up with git sometimes but since i already pushed most of the code on Github or Bitbucket i could simply pull it from the remote repository. That may be a painfull lesson but a version control software will greatly benefit you in the long term.

Comment: @mab0189 i aggree. This time i was not careful, and it was initialisation of repo after 1 week of work, first init, so it was not published yet. I had all the source on local machine, thats why source control is not an option for me. I am talking about a tool like [this](https://github.com/kse/cwatch) but more user friendly.

Comment: Eclipse has "Restore from Local History" - right click on the project and select that option to see what it has.

Comment: @greg-449 you just restored half of my work! Thank you! Alas, another half will need to be redone...

Comment: Note: you can configure local history to keep more in the Preferences in "General > Workspace > Local History".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and to regularly push the changes you made to the online repository. You will benefit more from the usage of a [version control software](https://bitbucket.org/product/en/version-control-software) then from a local backup. You can use either of them for free.

Comment: Believe it or not, actually i deleted everything playing with git commands... i want something completely different. if there exists. Something automatic upon file save.

Comment: Ok, i am not sure, but [cwatch](https://github.com/kse/cwatch) can be a linux solution to my question.